Troubleshooting 535 5.7.139: SmtpClientAuthentication Disabled Error in MailKit
I have a question. I had this code that used to work perfectly for sending emails using MailKit. However, I recently started getting this error message:
535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Mailbox.
Here’s the code I’m using:

using System;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("User Example", "example@domain.com"));
            message.Subject = "Correo de prueba";

            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = "Este es un correo de prueba enviado con MailKit."
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                client.Authenticate("example@domain.com", "password");
                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error al enviar el correo: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

I have already tried the following solutions:
Changing the credentials to my Active Directory credentials.
Modifying the SMTP configuration for ports, security options, and servers.
Ensuring SMTP authentication is enabled on my account (as far as I know).
Is there any additional configuration or a workaround I might be missing? Could this be related to new security policies in Office365? Thanks in advance!

Did you follow the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission
